# Issues with amp-list and nav-elements

Tags: amp-html

Because I'm making a multipage website I put my sidebar navigation in a json-file.
This works fine. Here's the code:

```
<amp-sidebar id="header-sidebar" class="ampstart-sidebar px3" layout="nodisplay">
  <div class="flex justify-start items-center ampstart-sidebar-header">
    <div role="button" aria-label="close sidebar" on="tap:header-sidebar.toggle" tabindex="0" class="ampstart-navbar-trigger items-start">✕</div>
  </div>
  <nav class="ampstart-sidebar-nav ampstart-nav">
      <ul class="list-reset m0 p0 ampstart-label">
          <amp-list width="auto"
                    height="400"
                    src="json/sidenav.json">
              <template type="amp-mustache"
                        id="amp-template-sidebar">
                  <li class="ampstart-nav-item "><a class="ampstart-nav-link" href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></li>
              </template>
          </amp-list>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</amp-sidebar>
```

But I need to set the height. Is this to correct way? Or can/should I set a more dynamic height? It is possible I will add new links to the json making the initial height too small and thus I need to adjust all pages again.

**Second question**
I want to show the same links in my footer as well.
I can't get them to show. Manual links are working:

```
  <footer class="ampstart-footer flex flex-column items-center px3 ">
      <nav class="ampstart-footer-nav">
          <ul class="list-reset flex flex-wrap mb3">
              <li class="px1"><a class="text-decoration-none ampstart-label" href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="px1"><a class="text-decoration-none ampstart-label" href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="px1"><a class="text-decoration-none ampstart-label" href="#">Terms</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
```

But using the json the links only show up when I change the width of `amp-list` from `auto` to a number. And then the links are below each other (vertically) instead of horizontally.

```
<footer class="ampstart-footer flex flex-column items-center px3">
    <nav class="ampstart-footer-nav">
        <ul class="list-reset flex flex-wrap mb3">
            <amp-list width="auto"
                      height="100"
                      layout="responsive"
                      src="json/sidenav.json">
                <template type="amp-mustache"
                          id="amp-template-footer">
                        <li class="px1"><a class="text-decoration-none ampstart-label" href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></li>
                </template>
            </amp-list>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:**

amp-list can not get the height of the elements on its own (ie; height: 100%), unfortunately. You can set the initial height using a little code though. I have used PHP to echo out the number of items in the JSON array and multiplied that by the height of each element. My solution to this problem was something like this:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="<?php echo file_get_contents('ABSOLUTE DIRECTORY PATH/count.txt')*70; ?>" [height]="inventory.listSrc.length*70" layout="fixed-height" src="json/all.json" [src]="inventory.listSrc">
```

A bit funky, but I already had the number of items from a for loop that created my JSON file, so I just outputted my loop counter (+1 to account for starting at 0) to a txt file and grabbed the contents of that. I then used [height] to change the height on my change events I had happening on the page - sounds like it may not apply with your situation.

**Second Question:**

When using layout="responsive", a width and height must be defined as an absolute so it knows what aspect ratio to adjust to when scaling the page. If you want to use width="auto" you may want to look at using another layout type supported by amp-list: [see supported layouts here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list).

As for the layout of the links, I'm assuming it's just a CSS issue. I am assuming you're apply float: left to the elements, but without seeing your CSS I can't be too much help there. I know amp-list may mess with the inside elements, so you may want to start by reference the parent object outside of amp-list and then reference into the element from there (ie; ul.list-reset li {float: left;}).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It took some time before my certificate was up and running. I published my site: https://josephiena.nl/ I solved my first question by moving the social icons above the list and give the rest of the sidebar height to aw-list.
My second question I solved partially. I changed the items to span instead of li and now they float horizontally. But on small screens it doesn't fit anymore. I need to look at that more closely. As suggested, it is probably some css issue.